# Какие технологии или сервисы использовать для генерации текстовых отзывов на основе нейросетей?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Есть такая задача.
У нас имеется огромная база отзывов на определенные бренды/продукты.
Мне нужно сгенерировать на новый продукт более-менее осмысленный отзыв на основе обученной модели по этой базе.
Я могу спарсить какие-то вводные данные по этому продукту из сети и на их основе + на основе обученной нейронки сгенерировать отзыв по этому продукту.

1. Такое сейчас реально?
2. Писать приложение лучше самим или есть сервисы предоставляющие такие услуги?
3. Если писать самим, то какие технологии лучше для этого использовать?
4. Можно ли как-то задать разделение отзыва на положительные свойства продукта и отрицательные?

Comment: Задача интересная, но, думаю, вам с этим лучше в ods.ai куда-нибудь, тут мало знатоков нейросетей.